# Removing item from state array in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-state

I have a function component in React called `Spec` which has a list of Blocks with the below interface. `Spec` maintains a list of blocks that users an add to, edit, or delete.

**Issue**: The delete action is not working as intended.

1. If there's only one block, then it does nothing, and the first `console.log()` in the function returns an empty array (it should be length 1), and the second `console.log()` returns an array of length 1 (it should be empty)
2. If there are more than two blocks in the array, no matter which `index` I delete, the final `(n-1)` elements of the array are deleted

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
//types.d.ts

interface Block extends Array {
  type: string,
  block: StoryBlock | MarkdownBlock
}

interface StoryBlock {
  title: string,
  description: string,
  visibility: boolean,
  status: string,
}

interface MarkdownBlock {
  title: string,
  description: string,
  visibility: boolean,
}
```

```
const Spec: React.FC<OptSpecProps> = (props) => {
    const [blocks, setBlocks] = useState<Block[]>([]);

...

  const addBlock = (type: string) => {
    let blockSeed;
    switch (type) {
      case "story":
        blockSeed = emptyStoryData;
        break;
      case "markdown":
        blockSeed = emptyMarkdownText
        break;
      default:
        blockSeed = emptyMarkdownText
        break;
    }
    const newBlockArray = blocks.concat({type: type, block: blockSeed})
    setBlocks([...newBlockArray]);
  };

  const removeBlock = (index: number) => {
    console.log(blocks) //This logs an empty array
    const newBlockArray = blocks.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(newBlockArray) // this logs the correct array
    setBlocks([...newBlockArray])
  }

  const updateBlock = (index: number, type: string, block: StoryBlock | MarkdownBlock) => {
    let newBlockArray: Block[] = blocks;
    newBlockArray[index] = {type: type, block: block};
    newBlockArray.forEach((block_itr: Block, i: number) => {
      if (i === index) {
        block_itr.block = block
        block_itr.block.visibility = true
      } else {
        block_itr.block.visibility = false
      }
    })
    setBlocks([...newBlockArray]);
  };
```

Here is a link to a [simplified component sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-hellman-jhpcu?file=/src/App.js), but it looks from the comments we've identified the issue

Comment: FYI—Calling `setBlocks` will not immediately update the state. It won't update until the component rerenders.

Comment: try using `useCallback` hook for defining `removeBlock` function

Comment: @ToddSkelton I'm checking the `blocks` on each render using `useEffect` and it's not updating. So I think that means it's not even updating the state? And still unclear to me why `blocks` first logs to `undefined` in the function even though I can see it in the view

Comment: @MeghdadHadidi thanks for the suggestion. I tried adding it to the `removeBlock` and it didn't help. Also added it to all function just in case, but still no luck

Comment: Hmm, yeah that's odd. Can you post a simplified component that we can test?

Comment: I can bet dollars to donuts you're using the `index` as the `key` when rendering the blocks. You can't do that for mutable lists, each block needs its own unique identifier as the `key` prop

Comment: Agree with @Jayce444, this is the exact behavior of using the index as the key, because deleting any element causes the array to shorten and the element react determines needs unmounting is the last index.

Comment: Got it, thanks folks. Just posted a sandbox link, but you were spot on. Feel free to leave something in the answers field and we can get this closed. Appreciate the guidance

Comment: you are also mutating state directly with splice, this is wrong. you should be doing a copy first from your array, not handling directly

Comment: `splice` returns the removed items, it doesn't return a new array with items removed.

Comment: The fix on `splice` solved it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, along with the recommendation on not using `index` as `key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the new block to the result of the `splice()` method, although, that method mutates the array in place and returns the **removed** elements.
Instead, you should clone the array and then splice it

```
const removeBlock = (index: number) => {
  const newBlockArray = [...blocks];
  newBlockArray.splice(index, 1);
  setBlocks(newBlockArray)
}
```

P.S. Be aware that the above performs a shallow copy of the array, but it should not be a problem in this case.